# Hidden Service Behind a Bridge

Tags: onion-services, relays, bridge

Without a bridge, my hidden service is accessible for others. But when I use a tor bridge, this hidden service is not accessible.

My `torrc` is:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge obfs4 my_bridge_ip:my_bridge_port my_bridge cert=XPoeAfCXs... iat-mode=0
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
```

The `tor` version is:

```
$ tor --version
Tor version 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930).
```

The tor bridge is working well, and the `tor` works well with this bridge. I also tested my bridge with `TorBrowser`.

Did I miss something for using hidden service behind a bridge?

My bridge is private and not available in BridgeDB. Must I add it to BridgeDB to enable the hidden service accessible from outside?

Comment: Hi, try this: sudo systemctl stop tor.

enable the bridge and the onion service in your torrc

start tor with just: tor (as a normal user)

CTRL-c to stop

then remove the bridge and try again. 

Put the output of each time your start tor into pastebin.com and remove and personal information (IP, etc) and the bridge URL if it is there and reply here.

You can start tor normally when this is done. This is just to get the startup logs.

Comment: @JSEvans, the startup logs are here: https://pastebin.com/Jf1zL8v8, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I think, I came across similar issue. I use obsf4 bridge to hide a server that my onion website is running on, and I noticed that sometimes my onion goes down. I then have to change bridges IPs and then, after Tor restart the onion becomes available again. I think the bridges are sometimes blacklisted by ISP or just pass away from different reasons.

However I think it might be also a case that bridge admins might don't want to have too much traffic on their machines. I posted a separate question on that:

[Do bridge admins blacklist IPs?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22627/do-bridge-admins-blacklist-ips)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this task I used to have this setup and it proved itself to be bulletproof:

- You have your onion site - either balanced by OnionBalance or not - on your servers. If you do have a balanced setup - repeat it for every node
- You arise a *separated* Tor instances with the bridge server on really static IP's
- You connect your site instances to your bridges